# htaccess conditional redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have by google indexed couple of tags as it follows `domain.com/tag-name`. Because of incompatibilities between my wordpress plugins this structure had to be changed to `domain.com/tag/tag-name`, on the other side all my posts are having almost the same structure as the indexed tag url `domain.com/pots-name`. Is there a way to create a a conditional pattern with htaccess to redirect `domain.com/tag-name` to `domain.com/tag/tag-name` if the the http response is 404?

Comment: If you know the tags and the yare not a lot, you can add a simple rewrite rule

Comment: I now my tags but there ate quite a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom 404 php page and redirect from there.

Add the following line to your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404_redirect.php
```

and create your custom 404_redirect.php:

```
<?php
if (should_redirect($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . get_redirect_target($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']));
} else {
    print_default_404_page();
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. It sound good what you suggested I already have a custom 404 page. I'm going to give a try with it